# Can Anybody Explain to Me What This Line Does in c#?

Tags: c#, properties, expression

I have don't understand the `<...>` syntax, is this is function?
Could anyone explain me this line of code?

```
ApplyPropertyChange<AgreementTransaction, int>(ref _agreementId, o => o.AgreementId, value);
```

Comment: `=>` is the [lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) operator

Comment: and from where does the lamba expression  takes the parameter "o"?

Comment: Read the linked page. It explains lambdas in depth.

Comment: Do you stumble over the meaning of `<` and `>` or the meaning of the `o => o...`-syntax? From your question I suppose it is the first, whilst the comments assume the latter.

Comment: yes, i am cofusing about the < > token

Comment: In that case, you are looking for [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the named of the method (`ApplyPropertyChange`) and the type of arguments, that looks like a setter for an element in a set of elements. The `<>` use is to pass the type of element, in this case it is an `AgreementTransaction`; the second argument of type `int` is most likely what to expect value to be or the result of the `Func` to be.

> ApplyPropertyChange(ref _agreementId, o => o.AgreementId, value);

It looks like it is taking the set of elements, finding the element in the set by using its AgreementId, and then setting the value shown.

It could in some ways be rewritten like this at a basic level.

```
foreach(AgreementTransaction el in setOfElements)
{
    if( (int)el.AgreementId == _agreementId )
    {
        el.AgreementId = value;
    }
}
```

The `Func<>` passed in is referred to as a predicate. It is essentially a delegate which will project an `AgreementTransaction` into an int.

Think of it like this:

```
AgreementTransactions.Select( o => o.AgreementId );
```

or in a broader example:

```
List<AgreementTransaction> AgreementTransactions = someListOfThem;
List<int> result = new List<int>();
foreach(AgreementTransaction agree in AgreementTransactions)
{
    result.Add(agree.AgreementId);
}
```

Overall, there is a lot more going on that I will not get into with regards to Lambda expressions, Func declarations, and delegates. You can read more on that from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This syntax:

```
o => o.AgreementId
```

is the use of the [lambda operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Specifically, this creates an anonymous function that takes one parameter, named `o`, and where the body is simply `return o.AgreementId`.

So this:

```
o => o.AgreementId
```

is short-hand for this:

```
delegate(var o)
{
    return o.AgreementId;
}
```

however you can't really specify `var o` like that, but for the lambda operator the compiler can infer the right type for `o` depending on the delegate the function is fitted into, and this is where you need to go to the `ApplyPropertyChange` method, most likely it looks something like this:

```
public void ApplyPropertyChange<T1,T2>(ref T2 value, Func<T1,T2> getValue, T1 inputValue)
```

in which case `T1` and `T2` are inferred from `o.AgreementId` and `ref _agreementId`.

Answer (score 1):

=> Is the lambda operator. Some people say that you pronounce it as "goes to". It is a shortcut for a delegate.

Maybe the sentence above holds several new concepts for you. The idea behind a delegate is that you don't give the value as a parameter of a function, but a function. In fact the parameter is a value, but the value is not an integer, or an object; it is of a function type.

If you call a function like *F(x)* and you you give a value 4 as a parameter, you'll tell this function that whenever it sees the letter X it should use the value 4.

The same is with delegate. If you have a function with a delegate D as a parameter and you call it with the parameter Sin(x) you say to the function that whenever it uses a call to D it should call Sin(x).

The traditional way of using delegates involved quite some typing. With the introduction of lambda expression this was made much easier.

The lambda expression is heavily used in Linq. Whenever you need to do things with sequences like arrays / lists / collections / sets, whatever, and you would normally use foreach Linq will make live easier for you.

For example, let's say you'll have a sequence of Persons. I use here the term sequence, because I don't care whether it is an array, a list, a set, a collection, whatever. The only think I demand from it is that I can ask for the first element and for the next element in the sequence until there are no more elements. In short: I demand that the sequence is Enumerable.

Suppose from this sequence I only want the Persons with a value for the FirstName property "John". For this the static function [Enumerable.Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is used. The result is an IEnumerable of the same type as my original sequence:

```
IEnumerable<Person> personsNamedJohn = Persons
    .Where(p => p.FirstName == "John");
```

Here you'll see the =>. You could phrase it as:

From the sequence Persons, take each person (let's call it p), where p.FirstName == "John".

I quite often keep it readable by giving my sequences a plural identifier (Persons) and instead of p I write the singular identifier:

```
IEnumerable<Person> personsNamedJohn = Persons
    .Where(person => person.FirstName == "John");
IEnumerable<Shape> circles = Shapes
    .Where(shape => shape.ShapeType == Shape.Circle);
```

There are a lot of other Linq functions where you use lambda. We saw that the function where gives you the elements of the sequence that match the predicate. The function Select will use each item of the sequence to create another item.

```
IEnumerable<Address> addressesOfPersonsNamedJohn = Persons
    .Where(person => person.FirstName == "John")
    .Select(person => new Address(person.Street, person.City, person.ZIP));
```

This is: from all Persons, take only the persons whith a firstname of "John", and from each of these persons take the Street, City and ZIP property as parameters for the constructor of an Address object. The result is a sequence of Addresses.

In the beginning I found the use of the lambda operator quite confusing, but once I understood it, it became very useful. Whenever I would write foreach, I find that it can quite often be written much shorter and easier to understand if I use a Linq statement with a lambda expression.

[The standard linq operatores](http://odetocode.com/articles/739.aspx) was a good starting point for me to understand linq, delegates and lambda